# Is it possible to attach a UISwitch to a certain CCLayer in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using a UISwitch in my cocos2d project like so:

```
//header file

UISwitch    *musicCtrl;

//implementation file


        musicCtrl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 0, 0)];
        musicCtrl.on = YES;
        [musicCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(musicOnOff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView] addSubview:musicCtrl];
        musicCtrl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        [musicCtrl release];
```

I have attached the UISwitch to the openGLView but I need to be able to attach it to a certain CCLayer on the GLView. Is that possible? I can't seem to find a UISwitch alternative for cocos2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

You can only add UIKit views to the cocos2d view, or the main window. Either way, the UIKit view will be drawn above all of the cocos2d nodes. You can not add a UIKit view to a specific layer.

Specifically you can't add UIKit views to a cocos2d app in a way where some cocos2d nodes are drawn in front of and other nodes drawn behind the UIKit view. That is impossible.